# Will in-app reappear

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Here is tricky situation - I've got an app, but configured in-app purchases wrong way, so for good - I set in-app status `Cleared for Sale` to `NO` rather the delete it. After that I configured in-app proper way, and *upload new build* to AppStore, that was approved by Apple. So now I want enable in-app again.

My question - will latest build work properly with in-app purchases, that will be enabled?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, latest build **will properly work** with in-app purchases that will be enabled *after build was approved by Apple*. Apparently, it can take some time for in-app to reappear in the store